# How to classify entries in a query?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have three tables: student, assignment and subject. They have the following values:

**Student**

| student_id | student_name | subject_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | John MacEnroe | 11 |
| 2002 | May Rockwell | 13 |
| 2005 | James Cronwell | 13 |
| 2012 | Jane Crickett | 14 |

**Subject**

| subject_id | subject_name |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | Math |
| 13 | History |
| 14 | Biology |

**Assignments**

| student_id | subject_id | description | score | submission_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 11 | assignment 1 | 8.0 | 2021-05-13 20:15:20 |
| 2001 | 11 | assignment 2 | 8.0 | 2021-06-15 21:35:40 |
| 2005 | 13 | assignment 1 | 4.0 | 2021-05-13 19:05:30 |

I want to create a query that returns to me a list of all the students and the related subjects, with the status on each subject following the rule below, and also the date of the last assignment evaluation.

- if there is no score = **Pending**
- if score >= 5 = **Passed**
- if score < 5 = **Exam**

**Expected output:**

| student_name | subject_name | description | status | submission_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John MacEnroe | Math | assignment 1 | Passed | 2021-05-13 20:15:20 |
| John MacEnroe | Math | assignment 2 | Passed | 2021-06-15 21:35:40 |
| James Cronwell | History | assignment 1 | Exam | 2021-05-13 19:05:30 |
| May Rockwell | History |  | Pending |  |
| Jane Crickett | Biology |  | Pending |  |

I tried using the code below, with no avail. I got stucked. I aprecciate any help.

```
SELECT 
 student_name
,subject_name
,submission_date
 from 
student
,subject
,assignments;
```

Comment: Avoid using implicit joins i.e. the comma separated style and write explicit joins instead i.e. `tableA join tableB on ...`

Comment: Read your SQL book (or tutorial or classroom notes) topics on `INNER JOIN` and `CASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
  s.`student_name`,
  sub.`subject_name`,
  IFNULL(a.`description`,'') description,
  (CASE WHEN a.`score` IS NULL THEN 'Pending'
        WHEN a.`score`>=5 THEN 'Passed'
        ELSE 'Exam' END) `status`,
  IFNULL(a.`submission_date` ,'') submission_date
FROM
  `student` s 
  LEFT JOIN `Subject` sub  ON s.`subject_id` = sub.`subject_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `Assignments` a  ON a.`student_id` = s.`student_id`
```

Selecting from multiple tables without table relations will give you
[Cartesian product of all associated tables](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-cross-join).